# Javascript -- Compare two arrays, return differences, BUT

Tags: javascript

I've found a lot of posts that solve this problem:

Assuming we have:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']; array2 = ['C', 'E'];
```

Is there a proven and fast solution to compare two arrays against each other, returning one array without the values appearing in both arrays (C and E here). Desired solution:

```
array3 = ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

But what if you have:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E']; array2 = ['D', 'E'];
```

and you're looking for the solution to be:

```
array3 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] // don't wipe out both D's
```

Here is some context:

You are trying to teach students about how sentences work. You give them a scrambled sentence:

ate -- cat -- mouse -- the -- the

They start typing an answer: The cat

You would like the prompt to now read:

ate -- mouse - the

At present, my code takes out both the's.

Here is what I've tried:
(zsentence is a copy of xsentence that will get manipulated by the code below, join()ed and put to screen)

```
for (i=0; i < answer_split.length; i++) {
for (j=0; j < xsentence.length; j++) {
        (function(){
            if (answer_split[i] == xsentence[j]) { zsentence.splice(j,1); return; }
        })();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the anonymous function and the return statement? As far as I can tell, neither of these does anything.

Comment: @JohnKugelman the anonymous function is a self-invoking one, so it does _something._ The `return`, OTOH, is useless.

Comment: @MattBall I mean why wrap the `if` statement in an anonymous function. It doesn't add anything.

Comment: In this case - that's true. I'm guessing it's a misapplication of [this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/139010).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just iterate over the array of elements you want to remove.

```
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E'];
var array2 = ['D', 'E'];
var index;

for (var i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
    index = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
    if (index > -1) {
        array1.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

It's `O(array1.length * array2.length)` but for reasonably small arrays and on modern hardware this shouldn't remotely cause an issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/puz7q/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: This is good. Your sample arrays are sorted. If this is the case, you can use a binary search to speed it up. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Deferred_detection_of_equality "if the keys are not unique, it returns the smallest index"

Comment: Thanks Matt. That .indexOf  section is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In this solution, you wouldn't be able to determine the cases when array2 is longer or contains 'F' and 'G' for example.

Comment: oops, I was taking the problem in a general sense of diffing 2 arrays - I suppose in this context you'll always have one array be a subset of another

Comment: @badunk regardless, the case you mentioned does not cause problems. Why do you think it might? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3zp66/

Comment: @MattBall sorry, misread the question originally and thought it applied to my own situation where I wanted to diff [a, b, c, d] and [c, b, e, f] to return [a], [b, c], and [e, f].

Answer (score 8):

You can use Filter also.
Please review below example.

```
var item = [2,3,4,5];
var oldItems = [2,3,6,8,9];
oldItems = oldItems.filter(n=>!item.includes(n))
```

so this will return [6,8,9]

and if you want to get only matched items then you have to write below code.

```
oldItems = oldItems.filter(n=>item.includes(n))
```

This will return [2,3] only.

Comment: I would recommend oldItems.filter(n => item.includes(n)); This is preferable to the accepted answer imo. No mutation and much cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks @milesaron!

Comment: var array1 = [1,-7,8,0,9];
var array2 = [0,-15,-7,1,8,9];
var oldItems = array1.filter(n=>!array2.includes(n));//output: []
var oldItems = array2.filter(n=>!array1.includes(n));//output: [-15]

could you please write a code that solves 2 cases